# SBT can not download dependency from 07.04.2023 - com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-js-engine

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

From today CI is not able to build the playframework project because of unresolved dependencies. I even cloned playframework sample hello world project - https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.8.x/play-java-hello-world-tutorial and result is same, same dependency are missing:

```
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-js-engine:1.2.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-js-engine;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:1.2.3
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-js-engine_2.12_1.0/1.2.3/sbt-js-engine-1.2.3.pom
```

```
not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-js-engine_2.12_1.0/1.2.3/sbt-js-engine-1.2.3.pom
```

Problem is with lib:

```
Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-js-engine;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:1.2.3
```

and when I check https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt all this dependency are missing.

Any action I can do? Or even information, why this artifacts were removed?

**UPDATE**:

repository: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/ redirect me to https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/lightbend/maven-releases/maven/
so maybe problem is with dl.cloudsmith.io?

**UPDATE #2**:

Looks like on sbt github repo, was created ticket related to this outage:  https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/7202 (Thanks @SethTisue)

Comment: yeah, the typesafe repo is currently down, haven't quite figured out who to tell yet.

Comment: the ticket on this transient outage was https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/7202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after removed all cached libs (on the mac: `~/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https`) sbt is able to download `sbt-js-engine` from repo.scala-sbt.org:

`https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml`

Answer (score 1):

If the source repository is public you could temporarily use https://jitpack.io and maybe the tag to get the new maven coordinates and get the build working.

This works with maven not sure if it is also working with sbt.